# Power supply unit from 230VAC to 12V, 5V, 3.3V DC

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pic, schematics

Is this power supply correct?
The capacistors are for decoupling. This power supply is for:

- 2x 2W fans
- 4x sensors (simple temperature, humidity)
- uC PIC24

*(the component 'Regulator' is LM7805)
*(trafo is 2VA power)
* Should i separate 12V, 5V, 3.3V GND?

Should i add something or change everything, give me your opinion.
Thanks in advance,
H.

[image]

Comment: Opinions sought usually end up in question closure. Without knowing the loading on the 5V and 3V3 lines nobody can opionate anything especially as you haven't stated what the TX secondary voltage is.

Comment: Secondary Voltage is 12VAC, i did not calculate the load but as i said earlier, this should supply only the fans, uC, and 4 small sensors :)

Comment: You need to be more specific. What are the specifications of the fan, sensors and PIC. How much current will they draw. How sensitive your analog signals are? How much ripple can you tolerate? These are important questions.

Comment: Why do you have a TVS on the input to each of the lower voltage regulator circuits? They're supplied by the 12V regulator...

Comment: Yeah i know it is bit pointless to add them :F

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem might be the power dissipation in the 12 V regulator. It can supply 1 amp (plus whatever load is on the other supplies) and, when doing so, there will be 12 V DC out and about 15.5 DC volts in. That's an internal dissipation of 3.5 watts. Added to this is that the 7812 regulator that supplies the 1+ A (if indeed it is a 7812) has a drop-out-voltage of typically 2 V and this means that the AC input voltage only has to drop to about 78% and the regulator is no longer regulating.

This is usually avoided using a 15 V AC secondary but then you get even bigger heat dissipation problems.

Comment: So, what should i do to make it better?

Comment: Use a low-drop-out switching regulator to produce 13V from a 15V AC secondary (rectified and smoothed) and then a low drop-out linear regulator to produce the 12V from the 13V. Alternatively just build it and live/cope with the heat dissipation and the occasional lack of full 12 volts.